# Beginner in Laravel not working my routes inside middleware guest, and middleware auth all routes working well

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

This is all my routes inside web.php

```
Route::get('/', function(){

return view('welcome-body');
});


Auth::routes();
Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('userdashboard')->middleware('auth');
// Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
// Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
Route::get('logout','Auth\LoginController@logout');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function ()
{
// About dropdown pages route
Route::get('/office-mayor', 'WebController@officemayor_about_page');
Route::get('/organizational-chart', 'WebController@organizationalchartpage');
Route::get('/directory', 'WebController@directorypage');
Route::get('/barangays', 'WebController@barangayspage');
Route::get('/barangays-detail', 'WebController@barangays_detail_page');
Route::get('/history', 'WebController@historypage');
// Stories & News dropdown pages route
Route::get('/stories', 'WebController@storiespage');
Route::get('/stories-detail', 'WebController@storiesdetailspage');
Route::get('/news', 'WebController@newspage');
Route::get('/news-detail', 'WebController@newsdetailspage');
Route::get('/gallery', 'WebController@gallerypage');
Route::get('/videos', 'WebController@videospage');
Route::get('/bids-and-awards', 'WebController@bidsandawardspage');
// Transparency route
Route::get('/transparency', 'WebController@transparencypage');
// Covid-19 update route
Route::get('/covid-updates', 'WebController@covidupdatespage');
});


Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function ()
{   
Route::get('authors/table', 'AllSystemController@indexauthorsdata')->name('authors.table');
Route::get('/authors/add', 'AllSystemController@createviewauthors')->name('create.authors');
Route::post('/authors/authorsdata/submit', 'AllSystemController@submitauthors')->name('submit.authors.data');
Route::get('/authors/view/{id}', 'AllSystemController@showviewauthors')->name('view.authors.data');
Route::get('/authors/edit/{id}', 'AllSystemController@editviewauthors')->name('edit.authors');
Route::patch('/authors/{id}', 'AllSystemController@updateauthordata')->name('update.authors.data');

Route::get('stories/table', 'AllSystemController@indexstoriesdata')->name('stories.table');
Route::get('/stories/add', 'AllSystemController@createviewstories')->name('create.stories');
Route::post('/stories/storiesdata/submit', 'AllSystemController@submitstories')->name('submit.stories.data');
Route::get('/stories/view/{id}', 'AllSystemController@showviewstories')->name('view.story.data');
Route::get('/stories/edit/{id}', 'AllSystemController@editviewstories')->name('edit.stories');
Route::patch('/stories/{id}', 'AllSystemController@updatestorydata')->name('update.story.data');

Route::get('activities/table', 'AllSystemController@indexactivitiesdata')->name('activities.table');
Route::get('/activities/add', 'AllSystemController@createviewactivities')->name('create.activities');
Route::post('/activities/activitiesdata/submit', 'AllSystemController@submitactivities')->name('submit.activities.data');
Route::get('/activities/view/{id}', 'AllSystemController@showviewactivities')->name('view.activity.data');
Route::get('/activities/edit/{id}', 'AllSystemController@editviewactivities')->name('edit.activities');
Route::patch('/activities/{id}', 'AllSystemController@updateactivitydata')->name('update.activity.data');

Route::get('blogs/table', 'AllSystemController@indexblogsdata')->name('blogs.table');
Route::get('/blogs/add', 'AllSystemController@createviewblogs')->name('create.blogs');
Route::post('/blogs/blogsdata/submit', 'AllSystemController@submitblogs')->name('submit.blogs.data');
Route::get('/blogs/view/{id}', 'AllSystemController@showviewblogs')->name('view.blog.data');
Route::get('/blogs/edit/{id}', 'AllSystemController@editviewblogs')->name('edit.blogs');
Route::patch('/blogs/{id}', 'AllSystemController@updateblogdata')->name('update.blog.data');

Route::get('news/table', 'AllSystemController@indexnewsdata')->name('news.table');
Route::get('/news/add', 'AllSystemController@createviewnews')->name('create.news');
Route::post('/news/newsdata/submit', 'AllSystemController@submitnews')->name('submit.news.data');
Route::get('/news/view/{id}', 'AllSystemController@showviewnews')->name('view.new.data');
Route::get('/news/edit/{id}', 'AllSystemController@editviewnews')->name('edit.news');
Route::patch('/news/{id}', 'AllSystemController@updatenewdata')->name('update.new.data');

Route::post('/storiesgallery/submit', 'AllSystemController@submitstoriesgallery')->name('add.stories.galleries');
Route::post('/activitiesgallery/submit', 'AllSystemController@submitactivitiesgallery')->name('add.activities.galleries');
Route::post('/blogsgallery/submit', 'AllSystemController@submitblogsgallery')->name('add.blogs.galleries');
Route::post('/newsgallery/submit', 'AllSystemController@submitnewsgallery')->name('add.news.galleries');

Route::get('contact_us', 'AllSystemController@indexcontactus')->name('sending.mail');
Route::post('contact_us/submit', 'AllSystemController@submitcontactus')->name('sending.mail');

});
```

and this is my Controller WebController

```
public function __contruct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

// TOP BAR PAGES
public function officemayor_about_page()
{
    return view('web-routes.about.office-mayor');
}

public function organizationalchartpage()
{
    return view('web-routes.organizational.organizational-chart');
}

public function directorypage()
{
    return view('web-routes.about.directory');
}

public function barangayspage()
{
    return view('web-routes.about.barangays');
}

public function barangays_detail_page()
{
    return view('web-routes.about.barangays-detail');
}

public function historypage()
{   
    return view('web-routes.about.history');
}

public function storiespage()
{
    return view('web-routes.stories.stories');
}

public function storiesdetailspage()
{
    return view('web-routes.stories.stories-detail');
}

public function newspage()
{
    return view('web-routes.news.news');
}

public function newsdetailspage()
{
    return view('web-routes.news.news-detail');
}

public function gallerypage()
{
    return view('web-routes.gallery.gallery');
}

public function videospage()
{
    return view('web-routes.video.videos');
}

public function bidsandawardspage()
{
    return view('web-routes.bids_awards.bids-and-awards');
}

public function officemayorpage()
{
    return view('web-routes.office-mayor.office-mayor');
}

public function covidupdatespage()
{
    return view('web-routes.covid-updates.covid-updates');
}

public function transparencypage()
{
    return view('web-routes.transparency.transparency');
}
```

if i want to go in the page example /office-mayor its return like this

error:
This page isn’t working right now localhost can't currently handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

I already use **config:cache**, **route:cache** and **dump-autoload** but doesn`t work it

How can i fix this...

Comment: Typo? `public function __contruct()` vs `public function __construct()` (Also no need to specify middleware in the controller if you have it in your routes already)

Comment: what is the 500 error in the logs say?

Comment: @kerbh0lz i already put s in __contruct() that i missed and i try to remove middleware inside controller still give me an error this : This page isn’t working right now localhost can't currently handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Never seen the use of `Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function ()`, shouldn't that be`Route::middleware(['guest'])->group(function ()`? I guess it's valid since your Auth routes seem to work. Anyway, do as Rooneyl suggested and take a look at your Laravel log, detailed error messages are appended at the bottom

Comment: @Rooneyl i already solve it thank you for the idea to look in log, i change my web browser to Google Chrome cuz i use Microsoft Edge

Comment: @kerbh0lz thank you for the idea same with Rooneyl ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is happening because you have misspelled constructor it should be like public function __construct() and you don't have to define middleware in your constructor because you have already used it in routes.